# Docker commands fail in Cygwin -- Docker service is up

Tags: docker, cygwin

I'm trying to login to my AWS account with a `docker login`string from `aws ecr get-login --region eu-west-1` -- however, when I do, I get this:

> Warning: failed to get default registry endpoint from daemon (error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.26/info: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.). Using system default: https://index.docker.io/v1/
>   error during connect: Post http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.26/auth: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running

The peculiar thing is this was just working last week. I'm using Cygwin on Windows 10. I've verified that Docker is running in `services.msc` -- I'm not entirely sure what to check now.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to run docker commands in cygwin on Windows 10, then call the following command from cygwin:

```
docker-machine env --shell=bash
```

It will show the environment variables needed by docker:

```
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.xx.xx:2376"
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="C:\Users\...\machines\default"
export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="default"
export COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS="true"
# Run this command to configure your shell:
# eval $(docker-machine env --shell=bash)
```

Run the following command to set the environment variables:

```
eval $(docker-machine env --shell=bash)
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to open a pipe to the service by passing a windows pipe path to cygwin. It gets interpreted as an http path by cygwin.

This is probably happening because the `docker` command finds the cygwin python before it finds the windows python. There are several solutions. The simplest is to switch back to a windows context to execute the docker command. If `docker` is actually `docker.bat` then start it with `cmd.exe /c docker.bat` otherwise `cmd.exe /c docker.exe`. You may also try `cmd.exe /c start /w /i docker.bat`. Or some variation.

You do not want to execute any `docker` command directly in cygwin as it will likely not know how to translate between windows paths and the linux paths it expects.